What is eating a young persimmon's leaves?
I have a Sweet Fuyu persimmon that was planted this Spring. Its leaves are being eaten up by something - what is it?


I occasionally find 1-3 tiny (~1/16") ants on it, which I remove when found.

There's also a spider there, which I do not remove. (Should I?)


Are you sure the ants aren't busy eating the insects chewing your leaves? Or do you have slugs in your area?

Not sure about the ants. We have slugs, but it is unlikely them: there's a barrier around this tree, and it is the upper leaves that get eaten.
